# Google App Script People API updateContact() Error 404

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, http-status-code-404, google-people-api

I'm using Google App Script to try to update google contacts with data from google sheet, but I received Error 404. I wonder what have I missed?

Here below my code.

I first gather data from sheet to arrays, then feed values of arrays into "resource", then I update contact by contact (because I don't know how to use the batchupdate).

```
function updateContactsFromSheet() {
  var sheetId = '[SheetID]';
  var sheetName = '[SheetName]';

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  var headerRow = data[0];
  var emailColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('Email');
  var firstNameColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('First Name');
  var middleNameColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('Middle Name');
  var lastNameColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('Last Name');
  var phoneColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('Mobile');
  var resourceNameColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('resourceName');
  var etagColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('etag');


  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {

    var resource = {
    names: [],
    emailAddresses: [],
    phoneNumbers: [],
    etag: []
  };

    var row = data[i];
    var email = row[emailColumnIndex];
    var firstName = row[firstNameColumnIndex];
    var middleName = row[middleNameColumnIndex];
    var lastName = row[lastNameColumnIndex];
    var phone = row[phoneColumnIndex];
    var resourceName = row[resourceNameColumnIndex];
    var etag =  row[etagColumnIndex];

    if(resourceName != ''){

    resource.names.push({
      givenName: firstName,
      middleName: middleName,
      familyName: lastName
    });
    resource.emailAddresses.push({ value: email });
    resource.phoneNumbers.push({ value: phone });
    resource.etag.push(etag);

    People.People.updateContact(resource, resource.resourceName);

  }
}
}


Here's the error:

HttpResponseException: Response Code: 404. Message: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### IMPORTANT:

**In this answer, if the values of `resourceName` and `etag` are invalid values, the script cannot be used. And, if you have no permission to update the contacts, this script cannot be used. Please be careful about this.**

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I think that `resource.resourceName` is undefined. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.
- In this case, it is required to use `updatePersonFields`.
- `etag` is required to be a string instead of an array.

When your showing script is modified with these modification points, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, your script is modified.

```js
function updateContactsFromSheet() {
  var sheetId = '[SheetID]';
  var sheetName = '[SheetName]';

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getDisplayValues();
  var headerRow = data[0];
  var emailColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('Email');
  var firstNameColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('First Name');
  var middleNameColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('Middle Name');
  var lastNameColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('Last Name');
  var phoneColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('Mobile');
  var resourceNameColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('resourceName');
  var etagColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('etag');
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var resource = { names: [], emailAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [] };
    var row = data[i];
    var email = row[emailColumnIndex];
    var firstName = row[firstNameColumnIndex];
    var middleName = row[middleNameColumnIndex];
    var lastName = row[lastNameColumnIndex];
    var phone = row[phoneColumnIndex];
    var resourceName = row[resourceNameColumnIndex];
    var etag = row[etagColumnIndex];
    if (resourceName != '') {
      resource.names.push({ givenName: firstName, middleName: middleName, familyName: lastName });
      resource.emailAddresses.push({ value: email });
      resource.phoneNumbers.push({ value: phone });
      resource.etag = etag;
      People.People.updateContact(resource, resourceName, { updatePersonFields: "names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers" });
    }
  }
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

From `because I don't know how to use the batchupdate`. if you wanted to use [Method: people.batchUpdateContacts](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/batchUpdateContacts), it becomes as follows.

```js
function updateContactsFromSheet() {
  var sheetId = '[SheetID]';
  var sheetName = '[SheetName]';

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var [headerRow, ...data] = dataRange.getDisplayValues();
  var emailColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('Email');
  var firstNameColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('First Name');
  var middleNameColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('Middle Name');
  var lastNameColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('Last Name');
  var phoneColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('Mobile');
  var resourceNameColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('resourceName');
  var etagColumnIndex = headerRow.indexOf('etag');
  var contacts = data.reduce((ar, row) => {
    var resource = { names: [], emailAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [] };
    var email = row[emailColumnIndex];
    var firstName = row[firstNameColumnIndex];
    var middleName = row[middleNameColumnIndex];
    var lastName = row[lastNameColumnIndex];
    var phone = row[phoneColumnIndex];
    var resourceName = row[resourceNameColumnIndex];
    var etag = row[etagColumnIndex];
    if (resourceName != '') {
      resource.names.push({ givenName: firstName, middleName: middleName, familyName: lastName });
      resource.emailAddresses.push({ value: email });
      resource.phoneNumbers.push({ value: phone });
      resource.etag = etag;
      ar.push([resourceName, resource]);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (contacts.length == 0) return;
  const reqs = [...Array(Math.ceil(contacts.length / 200))].map(_ => contacts.splice(0, 200).reduce((o, [a, b]) => (o[a] = b, o), {}));
  reqs.forEach(r => People.People.batchUpdateContacts({ contacts: r, updateMask: "names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers" }));
}
```

- In the case of `People.People.batchUpdateContacts`, the maximum chunk size is 200 contacts for every request.

#### Note:

- About both scripts, when the values of `resourceName` and `etag` are valid values and you have permission to update the contacts, the script works fine.

#### References:

- [Method: people.updateContact](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContact)
- [Method: people.batchUpdateContacts](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/batchUpdateContacts)

Comment: Thank you! I change resource.etag = etag to       resource.etag = People.People.get(resourceName, {personFields: "names"}).etag because those stored in sheet are not updated. 

Also, I want to update the UserDefined's value too, but since different contacts have different number of UserDefined field, how can I clear all those UserDefined during the batch update?

Comment: @user23506893 Thank you for replying. My proposed scripts are for your question. But, in your reply, your question is changed. But, I would like to support you with your 2nd question. So, first, can you resolve your initial question? So, I would like to resolve your questions in order. Can I ask you whether my proposed answer resolved your initial question? If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @user23506893 Thank you for your response. When I saw your new question, I would like to check it.